# How to create and call a method in a class with JLabel?

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to add a GUI to my code, but I can't seem to be able to create a method in one of my classes that has JLabel imported.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LeagueCalLifeSteal extends JFrame {
    private JLabel item2;
    public LeagueCalLifeSteal () {
        super("LS Calculation");

        Scanner New = new Scanner (System.in);
        int basems, boots, ench;
```

This is part of the current code, which has no errors but I can't call it on my main class because I can't create a method without getting an error, I tried placing the method code on many different places but I never managed to get it right.

```
  if (pick.equals ("LS") || pick.equals ("LS.")){
      LeagueCalLifeStealObject.LGCLifeSteal();
 }
```

This is the bit of code that I used to use to call the method from the main class, before I tried adding a GUI to it.

**EDIT:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class LeagueCalLifeSteal extends JFrame {
    public void LifeSteal() {  //Added the method statement
    private JLabel item2;  //Error on 'item2' "Illegal modifier for parameter 'item2';only final is permitted"
    public LeagueCalLifeSteal () { //Error on 'public' "Syntax error on token 'public', new expected"
        super("LS Calculation");

        Scanner New = new Scanner (System.in);
        int basems, boots, ench;
        int TotalAP, Rrank, Baseheal = 0, Heal, MaxH, Mh1, Mh2, Mh3,Mh4;
        double hptotal, hps;
        double LifeS, AttackD, WithSV, HPrest;

        System.out.println("message");
        AttackD = New.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("message");
        LifeS = New.nextDouble();

        HPrest = AttackD*LifeS/100;
        WithSV = HPrest + (HPrest*20/100);

        System.out.println("message");


    }
    }

}
```

This is the entire code of the class I'm trying to call, the errors are specified in it.

The class is supposed to be called once the user asks for it.

```
  if (pick.equals ("Lifesteal") || pick.equals ("LifeSteal") || pick.equals ("Lifesteal.") || pick.equals ("LifeSteal.") || pick.equals ("lifesteal")){
      LeagueCalLifeStealObject.LifeSteal();
 }
```

This is from the main class, if the user asks for the LifeSteal class it calls it.
But I can't seem to create a method in the LifeSteal class else I get errors on the JLabel code.

Comment: Can you please show full codes. Seems a simple problem which you are over looking at it.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you show us the error message. We're terrible at reading minds or guessing at stuff that we can't see. And what is this, `LeagueCalLifeStealObject.LGCLifeSteal();`, supposed to mean? It does not look like valid Java.

Comment: Having a JLabel imported has absolutely nothing to do with your error. Post the whole code and tell us what the error is. "_I tried placing the method code on many different places_" Instead of blindly copy/pasting and hoping things will work why don't you actually learn about these things?

Comment: This is actually me learning... And i'll edit the post right now

Comment: Added the rest of the codes with errors and further explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with importing or using JLabel and everything to do with

- you're declaring a variable as private *within* a method -- you can't and shouldn't do this as it has no meaning. A local variable is always invisible to anything outside that block.
- You've got a constructor nested within another method, another illegal construct in Java.

One quick solution is to add a closing brace for your LifeSteal method, so that you don't nest private fields and constructors:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class LeagueCalLifeSteal extends JFrame {
   public void LifeSteal() {
      // TODO: put code in this method
   }

   private JLabel item2;

   public LeagueCalLifeSteal() {
      super("LS Calculation");

      Scanner New = new Scanner(System.in);
      int basems, boots, ench;
      int TotalAP, Rrank, Baseheal = 0, Heal, MaxH, Mh1, Mh2, Mh3, Mh4;
      double hptotal, hps;
      double LifeS, AttackD, WithSV, HPrest;

      System.out.println("message");
      AttackD = New.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("message");
      LifeS = New.nextDouble();

      HPrest = AttackD * LifeS / 100;
      WithSV = HPrest + (HPrest * 20 / 100);

      System.out.println("message");

   }

}
```

But you may want to just scrap this code and start over, as you'll likely have better results. You'll also want to follow Java naming rules, giving methods and fields names that start with lower case letters and classes names that start with upper case letters.